# Python web template engine

Tags: python, templates, frameworks, web

I am looking for a python web templating engine that works like this:

```
<table>
  <%
  for item in items:
    %>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td><%= item.name %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
  %>
</table>
```

I have worked with PHP before so this seems nice to me. I have looked here http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating but I cant find exactly what Im looking for

Answer (score 4):

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) — inspired by Django templates, but much improved, text-based. And speaking of Django, you probably want to pick a framework before you pick a template engine.

Answer (score 2):

I would try [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/)

Answer (score 2):

It's a *lot* more than just a template engine...  But I'm a huge Django fan

https://djangoproject.com/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably looking for Jinja, http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

Also, you might want to familiarise yourself with Web2Py, Flask or Django.